# How to set value for a progressbar in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, progress-bar, vaadin

I am using a vaadin progressbar in groovy. I have a variables Total = 10, Right =5, left =3, I need to show Left=Total-(right+left), and visualize it in the progressbar.All are integer value.  In my code in am using a propertydatasource. How can i use these values and load into the progressabr. Please help. I am using vaadin 7.6.3.

Progressbar defining:

```
    private final ProgressBar _progress;
    public View() {

    _progress = new ProgressBar();
    _progress.setWidth("100%");
    _Layout.addComponents(_progress);  // here Layout is horizontal layout 
                                 fewcodes are missing which are not related.
    }
    public ProgressBar get_progress() {
            return _progress;
    }
```

In an another java class i am trying to set the progressbar data using the 'setPropertyDataSource' here '_view' is my Ui where i am trying to load.

```
_view.get_progress().setPropertyDataSource(_equipmentItem.getItemProperty(Equipment.Total));
```

The output i wanted to achieve is. 
[image]

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: I am using vaadin 7.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the examples from the docs? See [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-progressbar.html). Basically you can call `setValue` within range 0.0f to 1.0f (see [javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.3/com/vaadin/ui/ProgressBar.html#setValue(java.lang.Float))) where 0.0f is no progress and 1.0f is full progress. That means you can use `current / (float)max` formular to calculate your progress value.

Comment: i followed and i know regarding the progress values. My question was how am i able to get my integer values in to the setvalue of progressbar.

Comment: I guess you need `(Right+left)/(float)Total`.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you.

Comment: `_view.get_progress().setValue((Right+left)/(float)Total)`?

Comment: In my above code, I have mentioned setPropertyDataSource(... . But from your above code it sets the value directly. How can i use it.

Comment: Why do you use `setPropertyDataSource`? As far as I know, it is not necessary here, just use `setValue` on progress bar.

Comment: setPropertyDataSource i use it in order to set the data from an datasource. I think i can just use setvalue like you mentioned. But my code is "_view.get_progress().setvalue(_equipmentItem.getItemProperty(Equipment.Total));"  where, _equipmentItem is domainobjectitem. Equipment is my class having Total, as per my value it is 10.